# Solve by separation of variables $Z_{xy} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can do more complicated ones but this has me stumped, is it correct to reduce $Z_{xy} = 0$ to:

$X'(x) = 0$ and $Y'(y) = 0$ and solve from there?

Comment: What is $Z_{xy}$? Is it $Z(x,y)$? What are you taking the derivative with regards to?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1 (direct):**

In this case it is easier to solve the equation directly:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x} = 0$$

implies that $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}$ does not depend on $y$:

$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x} = f(x).$$

with an arbitrary function $f(x)$. From here:

$$Z(x,y) = \int f(x) dx + G(y),$$

where $G(y)$ is also arbitrary. After denoting $F(x)= \int{f(x)} dx$, the answer is:

$$ Z(x,y) = F(x) + G(y)$$

with arbitrary $F(x)$ and $G(y)$.

**Solution 2 (with separation of variables):**

For solutions that have a separable form $X(x)Y(y)$ the equation is reduced to $X_x Y_y = 0$. The latter has two classes of solutions:

i) $X(x) = const$, $Y(y)$ is arbitrary; i.e., $X(x)Y(y)$ is an arbitrary function $G(y)$

ii) $X(x)$ is arbitrary, $Y(y)=const$, i.e., $X(x)Y(y)$ is an arbitrary function $F(x)$

The linear combination of all solutions from i) and ii) yields the same answer as in Solution 1:
$$
Z(x,y) = F(x) + G(y)
$$